# App crashes when clicking button to insert/query database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, crash, android-sqlite

My Android app manages a database that handles patients of a private doctor. When I click the button to add an entry, the app crashes. It doesn't matter if I fill the form or not. I tried on Android device (Motorola G5S Plus, Android 8.1, API level 27) and on Android studio's virtual device (Nexus 5X, same APIs).

Agg_Pazienti.kt (the activity that should add the entries):

```
class Agg_Pazienti : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agg__pazienti)

        val database = CMHelper(this@Agg_Pazienti)

        agg_btn.setOnClickListener{
            val nome = nome_nuovo_paziente.text.toString()
            val cognome = cognome_nuovo_paziente.text.toString()
            val eta = eta_nuovo_paziente.text.toString().toInt()
            val telefono = telefono_nuovo_paziente.text.toString()

            /* Controllo Dati di input */

            if(nome == "" || cognome == ""){
                Toast.makeText(this@Agg_Pazienti, "Nome e Cognome non possono essere vuoti", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this@Agg_Pazienti, "Registrato con successo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                database.addPaziente(Paziente(nome, cognome, eta, telefono))
            }

        }
}
```

`CMHelper` class that inherits from `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
class CMHelper(context: Context) :
                SQLiteOpenHelper(context,
                                    DATABASE_NAME,
                                    null,
                                    DATABASE_VERSION){

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {

        val CREATE_TABLE_PAZIENTI = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_PAZIENTI(" +
                "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "$COLUMN_NOME TEXT," +
                "$COLUMN_COGNOME TEXT" +
                "$COLUMN_ETA INTEGER," +
                "$COLUMN_TELEFONO TEXT," +
                "$COLUMN_ANAMNESIPATOLOGICAREMOTA TEXT," +
                "$COLUMN_ANAMNESIPATOLOGICAPROSSIMA TEXT," +
                "$COLUMN_ANAMNESIOSTETRICA TEXT" +
                ")"

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PAZIENTI)

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase,
                           oldVersion: Int,
                           newVersion: Int) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_PAZIENTI")
        onCreate(db)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "cartella_medica.db"
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        const val TABLE_PAZIENTI = "pazienti"

        const val COLUMN_ID = "id"
        const val COLUMN_NOME = "nome"
        const val COLUMN_COGNOME = "cognome"
        const val COLUMN_ETA = "età"
        const val COLUMN_TELEFONO = "telefono"
        const val COLUMN_ANAMNESIPATOLOGICAREMOTA = "anamnesi patologica remota"
        const val COLUMN_ANAMNESIPATOLOGICAPROSSIMA = "anamnesi patologica prossima"
        const val COLUMN_ANAMNESIOSTETRICA = "anamnesi ostetrica"
    }

    fun addPaziente(paziente: Paziente){
        val values = ContentValues()

        values.put(COLUMN_NOME, paziente.nome)
        values.put(COLUMN_COGNOME, paziente.cognome)
        values.put(COLUMN_ETA, paziente.eta)
        values.put(COLUMN_TELEFONO, paziente.telefono)

        val db = this.writableDatabase

        db.insert(TABLE_PAZIENTI, null, values)
        db.close()
    }
```

Class `Paziente` that is the model of a patient's data structure:

```
class Paziente {
    var id:Int=0
    var nome:String?=null
    var cognome:String?=null
    var eta:Int?=null
    var telefono:String?=null
    var anamnesi_patologica_remota:String?=null
    var anamnesi_patologica_prossima:String?=null
    var anamnesi_ostetrica:String?=null

    constructor()

    constructor(nome:String, cognome:String, eta:Int?, telefono:String?){
        this.nome = nome
        this.cognome = cognome
        this.eta = eta
        this.telefono = telefono
    }

    constructor(id : Int,
                nome : String?,
                cognome : String?,
                eta : Int?,
                telefono : String?,
                anamnesi_patologica_remota : String?,
                anamnesi_patologica_prossima : String?,
                anamnesi_ostetrica : String?){

        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.eta = eta;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.anamnesi_patologica_remota = anamnesi_patologica_remota;
        this.anamnesi_patologica_prossima = anamnesi_patologica_prossima;
        this.anamnesi_ostetrica = anamnesi_ostetrica;
    }
}
```

What happens when I click the button to add entries in database:

[image]

Crash log:

```
2019-07-06 18:37:04.524 8022-8022/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 8022
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: anamnesi (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE pazienti(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nome TEXT,cognome TEXTetà INTEGER,telefono TEXT,anamnesi patologica remota TEXT,anamnesi patologica prossima TEXT,anamnesi ostetrica TEXT)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:501)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1752)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1682)
        at com.example.myapplication.dbhelper.CMHelper.onCreate(CMHelper.kt:28)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:333)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:238)
        at com.example.myapplication.dbhelper.CMHelper.addPaziente(CMHelper.kt:63)
        at com.example.myapplication.Agg_Pazienti$onCreate$1.onClick(Agg_Pazienti.kt:31)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Android studio doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column names should no have spaces.
You can enclose such names inside square brackets or backticks or double quotes.
I prefer square brackets:

```
const val COLUMN_ANAMNESIPATOLOGICAREMOTA = "[anamnesi patologica remota]"
const val COLUMN_ANAMNESIPATOLOGICAPROSSIMA = "[anamnesi patologica prossima]"
const val COLUMN_ANAMNESIOSTETRICA = "[anamnesi ostetrica]"
```

Also add a comma here like this:

```
val CREATE_TABLE_PAZIENTI = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_PAZIENTI(" +
                ....................................
                "$COLUMN_COGNOME TEXT," +
                ....................................
                ")"
```

After this change uninstall the app from the device and rerun.